# Cape of Wasps on large creatures

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, creature-size

How does the spell [Cape of Wasps](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/cape-of-wasps/) work on a large creature? If i get enlarged while it is active what happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RAW, it only fills “up to 5 feet by 5 feet,” and this means effectively *nothing at all*.

The buffs from *cape of wasps* aren’t really mechanically tied to the actual swarm at all. It grants retributive damage and concealment, or flight, as effects of the spell. RAW, the actual swarm that is summoned is effectively fluff in most situations—it only matters if someone shares your space with you and the swarm. And that means that when you are larger than the swarm, you still have those buffs. Creatures sharing spaces with you is a very unusual event in the system, so it’s really unlikely to come up.

Even in the unusual situation of someone mounting a druid or witch (“[Shame on you!](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Foocubus)”) with *cape of wasps*—which despite being unusual is still by-far the most likely way for someone to share the space of a Large or larger creature that has the spell—you use the mount’s entire space as your space and you are guaranteed to include the swarm’s space, subjecting you to its effects (seriously, those using *cape of wasps* should neither be nor use a mount, it’s cruel).

So RAW, the swarm stays “up to 5 feet by 5 feet” even as you grow larger, and it affects almost nothing. Which is a good thing, because it’s utterly unclear from the spell description which square that would be, and how that would work. Do you choose? Can you choose to move it later? How? When? And so on. And all of these kinds of questions are things Pathfinder usually tries hard to avoid—the game doesn’t have any concept of facing for exactly this reason. One of the most common causes of a creature to share another’s space in D&D 3.5e—grappling—was changed in Pathfinder to leave creatures adjacent. And even then, in 3.5e, it still just had you share spaces, just like mounted combat still does in Pathfinder, so that doesn’t have you figuring out where within the caster’s space you are.

All of which leads me to my point: **I think “up to 5 feet by 5 feet” is an error.** What it should be is “to a **minimum** of 5 feet by 5 feet.” Because the game doesn’t really handle sizes smaller than that—especially not for area effects like swarms. And read that way, we no longer have to worry about any of these problems. And for a 4th-level spell, that’s hardly an outrageous power point. It will still be a bit on the weak side.

Answer (score -1):

I think, by a strict reading of the spell, it should still function normally despite you being bigger than it.  It doesn't specify anything about needing attacks to pass through or target the concealed square to give concealment or the free poisonous attack - even though it mentions the possibility that it doesn't fill your entire space, showing the writers did in fact consider how the spell should work for creatures larger than Medium.

I wouldn't blame a GM for houseruling it, though.  Personally, I probably wouldn't grant the concealment unless the ranged attack needed to pass through the swarm square specifically, but I'd be ok with getting the swarm attack in melee.

Either way, though - the swarm's constant damage and distraction ability should only apply to creatures who manage to actually stand in the swarm's space for some reason, meaning they're also sharing a space with you, which is pretty uncommon.

Comment: I would just add on the last paragraph "but possible with creatures larger than Large or and/or smaller than Medium". Tiny creatures *must* enter creatures' space to attack them, and it's possible to enter a 2 size larger creature's space without significant penalty.

Comment: I think that if you’re going to recommend running things the way you suggest, you need to flesh out how that works. What square are they summoned into? How does that change as the caster moves? Can the caster move the swarm later? What kind of action is that? And so on. (All of which—along with the general lack of need to weaken the spell—being reasons that I take exactly the opposite stance and say that what should be houseruled is the 5-ft-square limit, or if anything it should be a minimum not a maximum.)